# long varchar to string

Tags: c#, .net, string, ado.net, varchar

I am using a long varchar column to store log information. Now I want to retrieve it to a string, in C#, using a DataReader. However, there is an error:

> Request to retrieve BLOB column which had already been accessed. BLOB
>   column may only be accessed once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this url will help you:

[Retrieving ntext, text, or image Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, buddy!You must be a Chinese!Haha!Where are you from?